# Sorting data in default rest api - Yii2 framework

Tags: yii2

I setup the default rest api in yii2 and it gives me the list of users when I run **"api/web/v1/users"** using **get** method.

Is there any way to sort the output data like **"api/web/v1/users?sort=name desc"** ?

Comment: I think you should implement it by yourself.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

See https://github.com/githubjeka/yii2-rest/blob/master/rest/versions/v1/controllers/PostController.php#L35

You can use $action->param or $_GET['sort'] for add to sort with dataProvider.

Comment: This is bad solution. Better check @SalemOuerdani's anwer. That functionality is built in REST YII2 controller.

Comment: SalemOuerdani's answer is about `$_GET['sort']` param. It'is same as my answer, but more detailed about `$_GET['sort']`. If you want to write other params, then you need to use `$action->param`. And default functionality is build in `BaseDataProvider::setSort()` , not in `Controller`

Answer (score 13):

There is no need to write code for it. Yii already supports inverse sorting by adding a negative sign to attribute name as shown [here [Yii core code]](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/56400add978427156673947e3c3d389674c93b56/framework/data/Sort.php#L247).

Unless **name** is not included in your model's safe attributes list, you can just use **sort=-name** instead of **sort=name desc** :

```
api/web/v1/users?sort=-name
```

- *Note: you can also chain sorting within commas : api/web/v1/users?sort=-name,id,-date*

Otherwise if your field is not a safe attribute or when advanced sorting is needed, then you'll have to override `IndexAction::prepareDataProvider` or configure it to return an [activeDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html#active-data-provider) which specifies how your [sorting](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-sorting.html) should work.

Comment: note in the data provider `sort` attribute, you may need to turn multi-sort on via `'enableMultiSort' => true`